# How to automatically show image upload thumbnails without submit in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, paperclip

I have a form with multiple file_field inputs (for images) being handled by Paperclip.

On my form, once I select an file to upload I want it to immediately upload (on selection!) and show the images thumbnail (without having to submit the completed form with the submit button)

I was able to submit the whole form via ajax using the remotipart gem... but im not sure how to achieve my goal.

Can anyone help? Please let me know if code or more explanation is needed. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd approach this problem in following way.

If you need to upload multiple files via XHR, use http://github.com/valums/file-uploader. It's a great plugin and it will suit your needs.

Once you set that up, you should create Rails controller to handle these file uploads (or use existing one). Since you are manually uploading files, you have to write upload function yourself and use paperclip to upload and connect with your Model.

Let's say you have a model called Photo. It has attached :photo.

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
  def upload_photo
    # In order to get contents of the POST request with the photo,
    # you need to read contents of request
    ajax_upload = params[:file].is_a(String)
    file_name = ajax_upload ? params[:file] : params[:file].original_filename
    extension = file_name.split('.').last

    # We have to create a temp file which is going to be used by Paperclip for
    # its upload
    tmp_file = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/file.#{extension}"
    file_id = 0

    # Check if file with the name exists and generate unique path
    while File.exists?(tmp_file) do
      tmp_file_path = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/file#{file_id}.#{extension}"
      id += 1
    end

    # Let's write the file from post request to unique location
    File.open(tmp_file_path, 'wb') do |f|
      if ajax_upload
        f.write request.body.read
      else
        f.write params[:file].read
      end
    end

    # Now that file is saved in temp location, we can use Paperclip to mimic one file
    # upload
    @photo = Photo.new :photo => File.open(tmp_file_path)

    # We'll return javascript to say that the file is uploaded and put its thumbnail in
    # HTML or whatever else you wanted to do with it
    respond_to do |format|
      if @photo.save
        format.js
      else
       format.js { render :json => { :errors => @photo.errors } }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is how you can do the AJAX upload of multiple files in Rails with Paperclip.

Comment: Hello, thanks for writing this code! However, doesnt this method require the form to be submitted before it can show the uploaded files? The first line says " # In order to get contents of the POST request with the photo, # you need to read contents of request" I'm trying to display the upload file, as soon as the user clicks "BROWSE" and selects the file (and it uploads successfully of course). WIll this work for that? Sorry if I'm misunderstanding. Thanks very much for the help

Comment: How do you expect to show something if you can't serve it from your end? You have to upload it to your server and then serve it. Yes, this works for that.

Answer (score 2):

why not break the file upload fields into individual forms. Then use jQuery to observe the file input field, if changed, then submit the form using ajax. Upon successfully uploaded, change the form into the thumbnail of the image uploaded.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Shanison. I am actually using a nested form for the  file fields (via the nested_form gem) to dynamically add file fields as needed... But I guess I need to wrap those in their own form_for?

If you know any examples of something like this online anywhere that would be really helpful. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any code examples for this. But I think it wouldn't be too difficult to implement it this way.I do a search and found out this http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/thumbnail-image-upload-ajaxphp. Use ajax to upload the files to server side and produce the thumbnails, then when click submit will submit the multiple files together. Demo: http://blogoola.com/signup/ This only have one file upload, but I think you can expand it.

Comment: hi Shanison, I've been trying to get this working but I am still stuck :( ... when you say split up the file inputs into individual forms, do you mean to use a fields_for block? or actually seperate form_for blocks? How would I include another form on my already exsisting form? can i have multiple form_fors in one view?

Comment: Hi Shanison, I just signed up just to give you a +1 because it's a smart and convenient approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that magically, you have to use Shanison's answer.   If you use ajax, you can make all appear seamless and fluid, but what actually will end up taking place is what Shanison described